# nginx with gunicorn flask app is blocking access of another user to my web app when this code is running

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, blocking

```
PAGE_GARDE = ""

def lecturePDF(self, fichier):
    resultat = ""
    info = pdfinfo_from_path(fichier, userpw=None, poppler_path=None)

    maxPages = info["Pages"]
    i = 1
    for page in range(1, maxPages + 1, 10):
        images = convert_from_path(fichier, dpi=200, first_page=page, last_page=min(page + 10 - 1, maxPages))
        if i==1:
            self.PAGE_GARDE = ('.').join(fichier.split('.')[:-1]) + str(i) + '_.jpg'
        for image in images:
            if i == 1:
                self.PAGE_GARDE = ('.').join(fichier.split('.')[:-1]) + str(i) + '_.jpg'
            image.save(('.').join(fichier.split('.')[:-1]) + str(i) + '_.jpg', 'JPEG')
            img = Image.open(('.').join(fichier.split('.')[:-1]) + str(i) + '_.jpg')
            resultat += pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")
            if i>=2 :
                os.remove(('.').join(fichier.split('.')[:-1]) + str(i) + '_.jpg')
            i += 1
            time.sleep(2)

    
    return resultat.lower()
```

whene i run my program on local with (flask run) on 127.0.0.1:5000 everything is ok i can open multiple page request during execution of this code but on server it stoped me until loop is finishing so i will be redirect to destination

Comment: Could you please add your gunicorn configuration? And command line parameters? Especially how many workers you have defined?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding --workers=10 to my gunicorn command.
Before it was

```
gunicorn app:app --timeout 0 –daemon --error-logfile
```

and now it becames

```
gunicorn app:app --workers=10 --timeout 0 –daemon --error-logfile
```

thanks everyday for your help